# Три функции python заменить одним методом

Tags: python, dry

Есть три функции:

```
    def test_post_index_page_show_correct_context(self):
    """Проверяем Context страницы index"""
    response = self.authorized_client.get(reverse('posts:index'))
    first_object = response.context['page_obj'][0]
    context_objects = {
        self.author.id: first_object.author.id,
        self.post.text: first_object.text,
        self.group.slug: first_object.group.slug,
        self.post.id: first_object.id,
    }
    for reverse_name, response_name in context_objects.items():
        with self.subTest(reverse_name=reverse_name):
            self.assertEqual(response_name, reverse_name)

def test_post_posts_groups_page_show_correct_context(self):
    """Проверяем Context страницы posts_groups"""
    response = self.authorized_client.get(
        reverse('posts:group_list', kwargs={'slug': self.group.slug}))
    first_object = response.context['page_obj'][0]
    context_objects = {
        self.author.id: first_object.author.id,
        self.post.text: first_object.text,
        self.group.slug: first_object.group.slug,
        self.post.id: first_object.id,
    }
    for reverse_name, response_name in context_objects.items():
        with self.subTest(reverse_name=reverse_name):
            self.assertEqual(response_name, reverse_name)

def test_post_profile_page_show_correct_context(self):
    """Проверяем Context страницы profile"""
    response = self.authorized_client.get(
        reverse('posts:profile', kwargs={
            'username': self.author.username}))
    first_object = response.context['page_obj'][0]
    context_objects = {
        self.author.id: first_object.author.id,
        self.post.text: first_object.text,
        self.group.slug: first_object.group.slug,
        self.post.id: first_object.id,
    }
    for reverse_name, response_name in context_objects.items():
        with self.subTest(reverse_name=reverse_name):
            self.assertEqual(response_name, reverse_name)
```

Нужно заменить их одним методом по принципу DRY.
Ревьюер в проекте мне указал: Ревьюер пишет:
"Код проверок контекста дублируется - проверку контекста можно вынести в отдельный метод и вызвать в самих тестах". Помогите, как это сделать?

Comment: можно кортеж создать для всех функций и потом вызывать его. Но, тут вероятно нужно сделать из трех функций одну? kort = (test_post_index_page_show_correct_context, test_post_posts_groups_page_show_correct_context, test_post_profile_page_show_correct_context)
kort[0](self)#1...2

Comment: Ну у вас же там только запросы в начале разные, а остальное тело функции одинаковое. Вот это одинаковое тело и выносите в отдельную функцию.

Comment: Нужен пример отдельной функции, не могу сообразить, как лучше сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я попробовал так, посмотрим, что ревьюер ответит:

```
def exttest_post_index_group_profile_page_show_correct_cont(self):
    """Проверяем Context страницы index, group, profile"""
    context = [
        self.authorized_client.get(reverse('posts:index')),
        self.authorized_client.get(reverse(
            'posts:group_list', kwargs={'slug': self.group.slug})),
        self.authorized_client.get(reverse(
            'posts:profile', kwargs={'username': self.author.username})),
    ]
    for response in context:
        first_object = response.context['page_obj'][0]
        context_objects = {
            self.author.id: first_object.author.id,
            self.post.text: first_object.text,
            self.group.slug: first_object.group.slug,
            self.post.id: first_object.id,
        }
        for reverse_name, response_name in context_objects.items():
            with self.subTest(reverse_name=reverse_name):
                self.assertEqual(response_name, reverse_name)
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Так:

```
def test_post_posts_groups_page_show_correct_context(self):
    """Проверяем Context страницы posts_groups"""
    response = self.authorized_client.get(
        reverse('posts:group_list', kwargs={'slug': self.group.slug}))

    self.check_context_is_correct(response)

def check_context_is_correct(self, response):
    first_object = response.context['page_obj'][0]
    context_objects = {
        self.author.id: first_object.author.id,
        self.post.text: first_object.text,
        self.group.slug: first_object.group.slug,
        self.post.id: first_object.id,
    }
    for reverse_name, response_name in context_objects.items():
        with self.subTest(reverse_name=reverse_name):
            self.assertEqual(response_name, reverse_name)
```